# How do I find the difference between 2 dates?(AngularCLI,NgbDateStruct)

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angular-cli

This is my html[image]

this is my component

model: NgbDateStruct

model2: NgbDateStruct

startDate:this.parserFormatter.format(this.model)

endDate: this.parserFormatter.format(this.model2)

example "parserFormat = 2020-04-30"

So how can ı find differences between 2 dates for example enddate - start date = 5 days

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please don't post images of code (not that the HTML is relevant here...)

Comment: it could be nice if you copy and paste the code as code instead of a screen shot

Comment: Actually I haven't tried anything so far I don't know how I can do something I haven't tried before. @KurtHamilton

Comment: @CemKocagöz pek kullanmayı bilmiyorum kusura bakma :D

Comment: @zafer How do you normally learn? Try thinking about what data structure you have, and what kinds of operations you might need to perform to be able to produce your desired output. Research those areas. My initial assessment is that you have 2 objects of type `NgbDateStruct`. These are not standard Javascript dates. Either there is a function built into `NgbDateStruct` to perform date operations, or you can convert to Javascript dates and find many relevant answers on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

use 
[momentjscom](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)
`npm install moment --save`

in your component:

```
import Moment from 'moment';
```

example:

```
  date1= Moment('2020-04-25');
  date2= Moment('2020-04-30');
  diff = this.date2.diff(this.date1, 'days');
  //diff = 5
```

Comment: here is the answer I am looking for thank you so much

Comment: I've never undestand use momentjs to know the difference between two Dates `diff=(Date1.getTime()-Date2.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000)`. It's good if we need make some more complex, but if only need the difference between 2 dates...

Answer (score 1):

you could convert date to milliseconds by using `Number(date_variable)` after that get difference between 2 date milliseconds. something like `Number(endDate) - Number(startDate)`. then you will have the time difference as milliseconds. Then you should use basic math to convert milliseconds to seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks etc.
For example i used a function like that before not good but it works

```
getTimeDifference(ms) {
    var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    if ((ms - one_day / 4) / (one_day * 365) >= 1) {
      return {
        time: Math.floor((ms - one_day / 4) / (one_day * 365)),
        type: " Year(s)",
      };
    } else if (ms / (one_day * 30) >= 1) {
      return { time: Math.floor(ms / (one_day * 30)), type: " Month(s)" };
    } else if (ms / (one_day * 7) >= 1) {
      return { time: Math.floor(ms / (one_day * 7)), type: " Week(s)" };
    } else if (ms / one_day >= 1) {
      return { time: Math.floor(ms / one_day), type: " Day(s)" };
    } else if (ms / (one_day / 24) >= 1) {
      return { time: Math.floor(ms / (one_day / 24)), type: " Hour(s)" };
    } else if (ms / 1000 / 60 >= 1) {
      return { time: Math.floor(ms / 1000 / 60), type: " Minute(s)" };
    } else {
      return { time: "", type: " Second(s)" };
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you ı will try

Answer (score 0):

According to ngb-date, this is just a container of date. So you can get the difference like the following:

```
const date1 = new Date('7/13/2010');
const date2 = new Date('12/15/2010');
const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
console.log(diffTime + " milliseconds");
console.log(diffDays + " days");
```